# C - Getting segmentation fault with the fgets() in a loop

Tags: c, loops, segmentation-fault, fgets

I'm new at C and I'm having some issues with my code. I'm trying to do a loop to read every input from a user, until he press ENTER and get out of the loop to execute other functions. Here's my code:

```
int main(char argc,char *argv[]){

    char input[200];
    char *epc;
    int err = 0;
    int idt = 0;

    while (fgets(input,200,stdin) != NULL){
        epc = strchr(input, ' ');
        idt = epc[2] - '0';

        if(idt == 1){
            err++;
        }

        }
    }
    printf("Success");
    return 0;
}
```

So basically if someone enters **5 01**, it should go through the loop, and then if the user
enters again nothing by pressing the ENTER key, it should break out of the loop and print Success.

Except it doesn't work and I'm getting a segmentation fault in the terminal every time.

If I do it with an artificial loop, example while(i<3) and i++ at the end of the loop to break, it does work.

Can you help me out please?

Comment: This is not complete code; variables are missing. Please post something we can look at and compile.

Comment: The updated code does not compile — there's one too many `}` in it.  You get the crash because when the user types a newline, `strchr()` returns NULL and you try to index off the null pointer, which never leads to happiness and usually leads to a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw is that you expect `fgets` to return `NULL` if the user presses just ENTER, but that's not what happens.  In that case, `fgets` returns just the newline, so `input` is the string "\n".  Then `strchr` tries to find a space in the string "\n" but there is none, so it returns `NULL` and then `espace[2]` dereferences `NULL` causing the segfault.

If you want the loop to break upon user pressing just ENTER, then you'll need to test for getting the string "\n".  You could do something like

```
 while (fgets(input,100,stdin) != NULL){
     if(input[0] == '\n'){
         break;
     }
```

Also note that there are other inputs that would cause problem.  Anything where the first space has less than 2 characters following it, (such as "0 1") will cause `espace[2]` to index to the string terminator or beyond.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing segmentation when you just press enter instead of giving some input, in that case your `strchr` returns `NULL` to `espace` and you are trying to extract something out of it by using `identification = espace[2] - '0';`

use below way to guard against the NULL handling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(char argc,char *argv[])
{
    char input[200];
    char *epc;
    int err = 0;
    int idt = 0;
    printf("Enter some words\n");
    
    while (fgets(input,100,stdin) != NULL){
        
        printf("input is : %s\n", input);
        
        epc = strchr(input, ' ');
        
        if(epc)
        {
            idt = epc[2] - '0';
            
            if(idt == 1){
                    err++;
                }
        }
    }
    printf("Success");
    return 0;
}
```